# Regular Expression for prompt of Ext.MessageBox

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs3

i prompt the user to fill the combination of alphabets and number.

Here is the code:

```
 Ext.Msg.show({
    title : 'you can enter alphabets and number',
    msg : 'Your value',
    buttons: Ext.Msg.OKCANCEL,
    scope : this,
    prompt:true
});
```

Although it prompt to fill the value, but in that field i want to add regular expression.

i dont want to add textfield or use the window.
Please help , if it is possible to add regular expression on prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said you do not want to use a window, but you could achieve this through a Window object with a form panel and a text field with a regex configured.

Something like this:

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();    
var win = new Ext.Window({
        title: 'You can enter alphabets and number',
        modal: true,
        items : [{
            xtype:'form',
            itemId: 'myForm',
            autoheight:true,
            width:300,
            padding:5,
            border:false,
            unstyled:true,
            style: 'background-color:#CCD8E7;',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Your value',
                regex: new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'),
                regexText: 'You must enter letters and numbers only',
                emptyText: 'Use Letters and Numbers'
            }],
            bbar: [{
                text:'Submit',
                handler: function() {
                    //Form submit here
                }
            }]

        }]
    });

    win.show();
```

Comment: why you use Ext.QuickTips.init();  ??

Comment: To show the tooltip error message when hovering over the field

Comment: thanks its working , but next issue is to make the same background color of items as the title have.
Checked the CSS but not able to find the same.
yeah i need the code in 3.4 version

Comment: See my edited code, I added unstyled and border config options, it can probably be tweaked some more, but this gets you most of the way there

Comment: See my extra edit, added a style property to the form. To be honest this is actually moving off topic from your original question. You should probably mark this as answer and then ask a new question on styling if that's all that remains now.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the prompt functionality of `Ext.Msg` is not intended to do such things.

In [NumberField prompt in ExtJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896474/numberfield-prompt-in-extjs) you can find 2 possible hacks to get this going. But they are hacks...

Comment: No. Look at the second answer (with 1 vote) you'll see adding a regex. Replace this regex with your desired regex.

In the first answer (4 votes) you can replace `return new Ext.form.field.Number(...)` by returning a textfield with a regex or whatever options you like.